# How to Track & Identifing only High Disk space consumed files in all directories recursively on the Filesystem Paths using AIX/Unix scripting?

Tags: bash, file, scripting, aix, disk

I've implemented below script, I need suggestions and inputs on below scripts.. Still this script can be improved better on filtering only non-binary files(including hidden files) and tracking the high disk used files in filesystem.

Any inputs?

Comment: Where is the script at?

Answer (score 0):

`df` and `du` just to see simple things like how much space remains on each mount point.

`find` to search for large files. You can pipe its output to a logfile and track that file, or have this find script run at certain intervals, or run as a daemon. The options for find are endless, but something simple like `find / -readable -size +1G` recursively finds all readable files above 1GB. It will have errors for directories you don't have permissions to, other options for that or just piping errors to `/dev/null`.